# Convert the sql query to linq

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have the following block of code which works fine;

```cs
var toDoSessionsInDB = from ZSESSION todo in todoZession.ZSESSIONs
                       select todo ;

ToDoZessions = new ObservableCollection<ZSESSION>(toDoSessionsInDB);
```

I wanted to modify the 'select' part, But the following code is throwing error

```cs
var toDoSessionsInDB = from ZSESSION todo in todoZession.ZSESSIONs
                       select  ContactName
                                  .Substring(0,c.ContactName.IndexOf(' ')),Age,ContactNumber;
ToDoZessions = new ObservableCollection<ZSESSION>(toDoSessionsInDB);
```

Following error shows before compilation ... ....
The best overloaded method match for *System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection.ObservableCollection(System.Collections.Generic.List) has some invalid arguments*

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to select more than one thing, you're going to need to `select new` in your LINQ.   It would look something like this:

```
var toDoSessionsInDB = from todo in todoZession.ZSESSIONs
                       select new ZSESSION
                       {
                         Name = todo.ContactName.Substring(0,c.ContactName.IndexOf(' ')),
                         Age = todo.Age,
                         ContactNumber = todo.ContactNumber
                       };
```

Where the items on the left side of the equals sign are the properties in your ZSESSION class.  You didn't provide that class, so I had to guess at their names.

Comment: var toDoSessionsInDB = from todo in todoZession.ZSESSIONs
                                      select new ZSESSION
                                       {
                                          ZTYPE = Convert.ToString(todo.ZENDTIME.TimeOfDay),
                                          ZNAME = todo.ZNAME,
                                          ZTRACK = todo.ZTRACK
                                       };

                ToDoZessions = new ObservableCollection<ZSESSION>(toDoSessionsInDB); error is ...Explicit construction of entity type 'App.MainPage+ZSESSION' in query is not allowed.

Comment: It looks like ZSESSION is an entity (or LinqToSQL class).  If you need to modify the data (like ZTYPE) on retrieveal, you'll need to create a new class that is not connected to the database.  Then you can select `newZSESSION { }`.

Comment: If i use the different class which is not connected to database class then the insertion to database part will not work. How do i manage both with same ObservableCollection ?

Comment: If you do what you were doing in your original query, you will select an `IQueryable` of ZSession.  The problem is, you seem to be changing something with the name.  Is this for display purposes?  If so, you might need to format things within the XAML - check out the `StringFormat` binding directive.

Comment: I created different class and used that properties in rt side of equal sign(because ZSESSION is database connected class) The Person Class is... public class Person{public string Name { get; set; }}. Following is the code to fetch and add to observable collection..var toDoSessionsInDB = from todo in todoZession.ZSESSIONs select new Person{ Name = todo.ZNAME };ToDoZessions = new ObservableCollection<Person>(toDoSessionsInDB); I binded this ToDoZessions to my grid. I want to Insert the data from observable collection on click of a button.How do I do that?